# How to remove a static background of a gif?

Tags: image-editing

I need to remove the background of a dancing character and get only that character to put on another backgrond. Someone know any ways to do it?
Gif:
http://deco-online.wikia.com/wiki/File:M-Sniper-Dance.gif

I already got the separate background, it was quite easy.
[background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEv6z.png)
All i need is to know how to get a sequence without that background, like this:
[clean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHIPK.png)

[EDIT]
I already know how to edit gifs by layers, i do it on Photoshop. I need a faster method to make it.

Comment: [How can I remove the background from a gif? - ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=29615)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to open this animated gif in Gimp. If you use "Open As Layers" instead of just "Open", Gimp will open all the frames in individual layers.

It appears that you would have to erase all the parts of the background behind the figure in each individual frame.

Comment: I usually do it on Photoshop.
I need a faster method, because i want to do it on 16 different gifs.

Comment: At least you can use the Pen Tool to outline it precisely. But, still not very fast. Can you open it or import it into separate frames in Photoshop? (I am asking in case anyone else looks at this post.)